# Basic Regex Expression Subsitution

Tags: java, regex

Is there a way to check if there is a regex match and then perform a substitution on part of the match?

Ex. -> "a3c" if "[1-9]c$" -> "a3" (if there is a "NUMc" at the end take off the "c")

specifically trying to generate a mapping a rules in to perform operations such as:

```
rule.put(String regex, String replacement) 
rule.put("[1-9]c$","");
```

to be able to call:

```
"a3c".replace(rule.key,rule.value) //delete just the "c" not the whole "3c".
```

Also I know that i can make an if statement to check if it matches and then call a replacement but i want to see if there is a neat one liner :)

Comment: You can use a lookbehind [`(?<=[1-9])c$`](https://regex101.com/r/bBeecu/1) to check the digit and then replace the match with a blank string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regex**: [`(\\d+)c$`](https://regex101.com/r/iCEG7a/2) **Substitution**: `$1`

**Details**:

- `()` Capturing group
- `\d` Matches a digit (equal to `[0-9]`)
- `+` Matches between one and unlimited times
- `$` Asserts position at the end of the string
- `$1` Group 1.

**Java code**:

```
String text = "a3c";
text = text.replaceAll("(\\d+)c$", "$1");
System.out.print(text); // a3
```

[Code demo](http://rextester.com/YQMR69436)

Comment: Good to know, exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!